# Cannot connect to Vagrant Homestead machine over particular network

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, networking, vagrant, homestead

I am using the Homestead development environment to build Laravel applications.

I am new to Vagrant so I do not have a lot of experience with it.

I have a weird problem which took me 4 days to identify but no clue where to start in fixing it.

I work for company which has a lot restrictions on their laptops so getting the Homestead machine up and running was a task in itself.

Now once the Homestead VM is up, I am not able to connect to that machine **when I am connect to the network at the office  - Note: specifically office network**. If I take the laptop home and try connecting to the VM when connected to my wifi at home, it works fine. If I am connected to the hotspot on my phone, it works fine. If I switch off the Wi-fi, it works fine. This took me a while to identify.

The error that I get when connected to the office network is **Network Error (tcp_error)**

I am able to SSH into the machine and run all types of commands. Everything works as expected from the terminal point of view. However the page does not load.

I am able to ping the VM from the command line and I get the response back so I know that the machine is running.

I even tried logging in to the laptop using highest administrator privileges but the issue was the same.

As I am the only person in the department who uses Vagrant, the IT team has no experience in this area and is unable to figure out what the issue could be.

I have tried everything that I can think of. Re-installing Vagrant, VBox, Homestead but nothing helps. It just comes back to the same point where I am stuck. I looked at the Firewall settings but I didn't see any app that looked like it was related to Vagrant and Virtual Box which was blocked.

Has anyone else faced a similar issue and found a workaround that could help?

I am using HP Elitebook - Windows 8.1 Pro 64 bit.

Thank you in advance.
Warren

Comment: quick question, this problem happens when you try to access the VM Server via browser to load the page? Have you tried open the page with the IP of the machine and also with the hosts file modification for virtual servers?

Comment: do you configure the VM with a fix IP , can you try to add that to your host file

Comment: @EliasRodrigues - Yes this problem is when I try to access my application with a browser. Eg: http://192.168.33.20/myapp 

Yes I am using the IP to access the server.  I have not yet set up a host map for the IP address.

Comment: @FrédéricHenri
The IP is 192.168.33.20. This is what I am using in the browser to access the server and applications.

Comment: Can you show us how it's your "Homestead.yml" it's at the moment specifically the section about the folders and sites.

Comment: can you try another IP, 192.168.xx.xx might be taken for local network. If you cannot find an accessible range free from your corporate network, just use public network and use forward port to access your VM site

Comment: @EliasRodrigues
[code]
folders:
    - map: C:/Warren/Server/projects
      to: /home/vagrant/projects

sites:
    - map: dev.cg.com
      to: /home/vagrant/projects/laravel/starter/public
[code]

Comment: @FrédéricHenri
I tried switching to 192.168.13.13 but no luck there either.

Comment: everything on 192.168.x.x will not work as its on corporate network

Comment: @Warren as Frédéric said since it's a corporate network the IP will have issues with it, so change the IP for the VM to something like "10.12.0.2" and for a better practice configure your hosts file ("dev.cg.com") and avoid using IP Address to access you VM in the browser.

Comment: @FrédéricHenri & Elias - I changed the IP to 5.5.5.5 and the issue remains the same. I updated the vagrant file as well as the homestead.yaml file.

I also checked using ifconfig in homestead ubuntu to ensure that the IP was 5.5.5.5

The response is below.
inet addr:5.5.5.5  Bcast:5.5.5.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

I also pinged 5.5.5.5 from the windows host machine and I got the response.

I also pinged 192.168.20.33 (the prev IP assigned) and the response was 'Destination Host unreachable'

I am stlll getting a Network Error when connecting from the browser.

Switched Wifi off - it works fine

Comment: Previous IP - 192.168.33.20 - Mistake in the above comment